# strut tags for iterating session variable

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am designing a web application where i want to use maximum of struts tag on JSP page instead of java code.

In my case,

one of the action is taking input from a JSP >> fetching data from db as per input >> populating Hashmap with output beans >> Putting hashmap into session >> iterating hashmap on JSP

**Why i need hashmap** : On the result JSP, i am generating link having Hashmap key as a parameter. So that the next action can get bean from HashMap easily without requesting to DB or any iteration.

**In Addition**: Before displaying data on result JSP, i require to format some of the data. I can not format this data while populating hashmap, because this data might be required further to store back into db.

How can i do above task using logic iterator and bean:write tags?

*I don't think that creating an extra form variable would be a better approach, instead of putting result bean into session variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Struts2/OGNL tags, you can access values from a map using `map[key]`.

**Reference:**

- Struts2 [`iterator` tag](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/iterator.html) reference and examples
- [Struts 2 OGNL Expression Language Example](http://www.vaannila.com/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-ognl-expression-language-example-1.html)

Regarding formatting, would you able to specify exactly what you need to format?